# Django Models Confusion

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to find the best Model to use for the following abstracted scenario. I'll paste what I have underneath but if anyone can suggest improvements that would be great- new to this and I can't find anything that with this use case in tutorials. Thanks in advance!

**Scenario**
Brad Pitt and Tom cruise share 10 cars. Each day they they choose the car they will drive.

Each day, their butler records who is using which car and the date it is being used.

I want to be able to see:
All the cars used by an individual and the associate dates
All the individuals who used a particular car, and the associate dates.

My Model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='FIRST')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='LAST')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Car_used(models.Model):
    used_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #Default to now?
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.car.name
```

So I'm using this Car_used class to store the car use each day, and who used it. Is this the best way to go about this?

Many many thanks guys!

S

Comment: Everything looks fine. It's really simple case. So, there is no way to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Consider renaming Car_used to CarUsed. That's is the convention.

You should also implement some mechanism to prevent two persons using same car on same day. You could add a unique_together constraint as follows.

```
class Car_used(models.Model):
    # Your code here.

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('used_on', 'car', 'person')
```

Also consider changing type of used_on to DateField if time is not important.